# Subtext - Missing Scripts

Tags: asp.net, subtext

I'm new to SubText, is there another location for the Docs?

Anyway, I've imported my sites template into the pagetemplate file in
the Naked skin. I now need to add 3 JS files. So i';ve done the
following,

```
<SkinTemplate Name="Naked" TemplateFolder="Naked"
StyleMergeMode="MergedAfter">
          <Styles>
                  <Style href="~/skins/_System/commonstyle.css" />
                  <Style href="~/skins/_System/commonlayout.css" />
          </Styles>
    <scripts>
      <Script Src="~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" />
      <Script Src="~/scripts/cufon-yui.js" />
      <Script Src="~/scripts/myriadPro_400.font.js" />
    </scripts>
  </SkinTemplate>
```

However these 3 JS files do not seem to be pulled through, they are in
the scripts folder. How can I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<scripts> should be <Scripts> (notice capitalization).

Try that and see if it works.